# React/Redux: Can't map over state [object Object]

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux, axios

Trying to orient through the dark depths of Redux-React-API jungle - managed to fetch data from API and console.log it - but neither me nor my Google skills have managed to find out why it doesn't render.

**React Components**

Parent Component:

```
class Instagram extends Component {
  componentWillMount(){
    this.props.fetchInfo();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="wrapper">
          <InstagramPost />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators({ fetchInfo }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Instagram);
```

Child Component:

```
class InstagramPost extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.info);
    this.props.info.map((p,i) => {
      console.log("PROPS ID: " + p.id);
    })

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>POSTS</h1>
        <ul className="uls">
          {
            this.props.info.map((inf, i) =>
              <li key={i}>{inf.id}</li>
            )
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ info }) => {
  return { info }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(InstagramPost);
```

Redux Action method:

```
const ROOT_URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

export const fetchInfo = () => {
  const request = axios.get(ROOT_URL);
  return {
    type: types.FETCH_INFO,
    payload: request
  };
}
```

Redux Reducer method:

```
export default function(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_INFO:
      return action.payload.data;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The JSON file looks like this:

[image]

In the console - it works and I get my Objects:

[image]
[image]

The state is also updated:

[image]

But when I map over *this.props.info*, trying to render *this.props.info.id*, nothing is rendered on the page.. Incredibly thankful for any input!

Comment: output you see in console is result of this line `console.log("PROPS: " + this.props.info);` ??

Comment: @MayankShukla Thank you for response! It's displayed in the image above "PROPS: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object].."

Comment: Try removing the `"PROPS: " + ` part, so you can inspect the objects.

Comment: @fransBernhard issue is you are not returning anything from map body, use this: `{this.props.info
            ? this.props.info.map((inf, i) => (
              <li key={i}>{inf.id}</li>
            ))
            : null
          }` or add `return` explicitly here : `return <li>....</li>`

Comment: @Oblosys Thank you for respone! I removed "PROPS: " and updated my screenshots in the question!

Comment: The comment by Mayank Shukla points out the problem. Just removing the braces around the `<li> .. </li>` expression should fix it.

Comment: @MayankShukla I updated my question to current code - but it didn't change anything

Comment: @Oblosys Updated my question to the current code, but didn't help to return :(

Comment: The extra checks are not necessary, since the reducer initializes the array to `[]`. Just use this: `{this.props.info.map((inf, i) => <li key={i}>{inf.id}</li>)}`

Comment: @Oblosys Updated the question - but still nothing renders and this.props.info.id still console "undefined"

Comment: The map not returning was indeed a problem, but another one seems to be that the state is an array containing an array. Try replacing the reducer case for `FETCH_INFO` with `return action.payload.data`. I have to go now, but I can put an explanation in an answer later if you like.

Comment: Now it works!!!! @Oblosys Thank you so much! If you have the time/energy you are so welcome to post the answer <3333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two problems. As Mayank Shukla pointed out, nothing was returned from the map callback because of the block braces (`{}`) without a return statement.

The other problem was in the reducer. As the redux state for `info` is an array of users, you need to replace the old state on `FETCH_INFO` rather than add the fetched array to the beginning of it. Otherwise, you're maintaining an array of arrays of users, which will grow by one on each fetch.

Note that you don't need any checks on `this.props.info`, as it will be initialized to `[]` by your reducer and `[].map(f) == []`.

For redux debugging I can very much recommend installing the [Redux DevTools extension](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension), as it will allow you to inspect all updates to the store. It needs a little setup per project, but that's well worth it.

Oh, and in the future, you might want to refrain from updating your question with suggestions from the comments/answers, as the question will no longer make sense to other visitors :-)

Comment: Thank you @Obiosys, for the answer and advice!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your props aren't set on the initial render. I'm guessing your API call hasn't finished.

Try checking the the variable is set or is an array first:

Something like this:

```
class InstagramPost extends Component {


render() {

    if(!this.props.info) return null

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>POSTS</h1>
        <ul className="uls">
          {
            this.props.info.map((inf, i) => {
              return <li key={i}>{inf.id}</li>
            })
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ info }) => {
  return { info }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(InstagramPost);
```

Or you may want to check the length `this.props.info.length > 0`.

Comment: But how does it matter if the props get loaded even at a later point in time it will re-render with the available data right ?

Comment: Yes you are right, but it looks like you are trying to call `.map()` on a variable that is undefined or is not an array and this is likely to throw an error and stop the initial render

Comment: @Stretch0 Thank you for response! I updated my question and screenchots. No I check if this.props.info exists - and also tried to console.log "this.props.info.id" in child component, which as you said console.logs "PROPS ID" undefeined :(

Comment: Ideally you should be having a `loading` boolean set to true when you begin fetching. This would help in avoiding these errors.
Also, if you need to simply iterate over a list, use `forEach`. `map` is used to rebuild an existing array.

Comment: @fransBernhard you need to return something from your map function. I have updated my example for you. I also moved the checking of the info variable to make it more clear.

Comment: @Stretch0 I updated my question to the current code, returning value, but id didn't make a difference :(